# Writing unsigned types to a Netty ChannelBuffer

Tags: java, netty

Netty's ChannelBuffer class provides convenient methods for reading unsigned types from a ChannelBuffer, however there don't appear to be any equivalent methods for writing unsigned types to a ChannelBuffer.

I feel like I must be missing something.  What's the recommended approach for say, writing an unsigned integer to a ChannelBuffer?

Thanks!

Comment: i think this may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write a 32-bit value its all the same.

```
channelBuffer.writeInt(my32bitValue);
```

Comment: Consider:

`long reallyBigUnsignedInt = inChannelBuffer.readUnsignedInt();`


Assume that reallyBigUnsignedInt exceeds the maximum for a signed int. What's the best way to write this value to another ChannelBuffer as an unsigned int?  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see.  Downcasting a large unsigned int stored as a long to an int "just works".

Comment: A 32-bit value is a value which uses 4 byte, what you make of it unsigned, signed, float etc is up to you when you read it.

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help you
[Can we make unsigned byte in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java)

you can just send msg like this.

```
byteBuf.writeByte(0x80);
```