# How to use ByteBuf write unsigned int Little Endian Byte Order in Netty4?

Tags: java, netty

In netty4 ByteBuf has a method read an unsigned int little endian

```
/**
 * Gets an unsigned 32-bit integer at the current {@code readerIndex}
 * in the Little Endian Byte Order and increases the {@code readerIndex}
 * by {@code 4} in this buffer.
 *
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
 *         if {@code this.readableBytes} is less than {@code 4}
 */
public abstract long  readUnsignedIntLE();
```

how to write a 32-bit unsigned number Little Endian Byte Order with ByteBuf?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing unsigned types to a Netty ChannelBuffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619743/writing-unsigned-types-to-a-netty-channelbuffer)

Comment: Thx ! Because I have an on Java signed and c unsigned conversion confused, now I know, I can call ByteBuf.writeInt ((int)longValue), it's working.