# How to convert csv byte string to byte array in Java?

Tags: java, string, arrays, type-conversion

I have a csv string to bytes and i want to convert it in java byte array. Can anyone help me.

csv string

```
167, 27, 32, 195
```

The byte array should be like this

```
byte[0] should give me 167
byte[1] should give me 27
byte[2] should give me 32
byte[3] should give me 195
```

Comment: Please note, in Java, byte ranges from -128 to 127, not 0 to 255!

Comment: this means i should use unsigned byte array, will this solve my problem?

Comment: Java doesn't have unsigned bytes, unfortunately.

Comment: So can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: In java, there is no such keyword 'unsigned'. You either need to use short, or let your program work fine with signed bytes.

Comment: thanks guys, i found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java), i hope this will also help anyone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array of characters.  The `char` type is intended to represent characters in Java.

```
String csv = "167, 27, 32, 195";
String[] numbers = csv.split(", ");
char[] chars = new char[numbers.length];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    chars[i] = (char)Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
```

This method assumes that the numbers in the CSV file are Unicode code points of the characters.

Comment: Its giving an error on `(char)numbers[i];` **cannot cast String to char**, well i have already fixed the problem you can see in comments of the question