# Checksum calculation in android/java

Tags: java, android

I wrote a checksum calculation function in android/java.  the function as follows

```
void CalculateCheckSum( byte[] bytes ){
     short CheckSum = 0, i = 0;
     for( i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++ ){
        CheckSum = (short) ((short)CheckSum + (short)bytes[i]);
     }

     Log.i("Checksum", Integer.toHexString(CheckSum));
}
```

input values for calculation of checksum are 0xEF, 0x01, 0xEF, 0x01, 0x33, 0x0C, 0xB8, 0xE5, 0xFC, 0x34, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF.  I manually calculated the checksum value and result is 0xCE4.  When using the above function i get answer as 0xFFFFFFE4.  Is any error in my calculation, if yes then please correct me.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`byte` according to [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html)  :

> The value of a byte is ranged between `2^(-7)` and `(2^7)-1` (-128 to 127).

But your value `0xEF` (in decimal 239) has already reached the limit of a byte. That's what cause the sum give the wrong numbers.

Comment: Is any data type that supports 8 bit value ( ie 0-255) in java

Comment: There is no `unsigned` primitive type in java afaik. But you can find other dependencies which provides `unsigned` type.

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java)

Comment: 0xEF fits into a byte. It just takes the value -17 when you use it in an expression. That by itself won't disturb the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Use a debugger and debug your code. Generally though, if you keep adding stuff up, even if you use an `int` or a `long`, it is bound to overflow at some point, so you will get unexpected results. Best to use a standard checksum algorithm or one of the already available classes such as `CRC32` or `Adler31`. As for your code, you seem to be treating the result as an integer, so why cast to `short` in the first place?

Java does all arithmetic calculations using `int`'s, so your `byte`s get converted to `int` and the ones that don't fit into a byte will look like this as `int`'s: `ffffffef` (-17). Naturally you only need the actual byte value, so you need to zero out everything else using `(0xff & b)`. So your loop than becomes something like this:

```
  int checkSum = 0;

  for(byte b : bytes){
    checkSum += (0xff & b);
  }
```

Comment: I want to send some packet to an embedded equipment that uses above checksum method to calculate.  so i can't change CRC32 or other

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the `(short)` cast of `bytes[i]`. It extends the sign. You should change `(short)bytes[i]` to `(bytes[i] & 0xff)`. This will give you the correct answer.

It has nothing to do with byte overflow, contrary to most of the other answers. You don't have to change the array type either.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above by aprian, while byte has the necessary 8 bits for your hex values, it can only store values between -128 and 127.
So a quick and easy solution would be to use the next bigger primitive, in this case `short`.

```
short shorts[] = {0xEF, 0x01, 0xEF, 0x01, 0x33, 0x0C, 0xB8, 0xE5, 0xFC, 0x34, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};

int checkSum = 0;

for( short s : shorts){
    checkSum = checkSum + s;
}

System.out.println("Checksum: " + Integer.toHexString(checkSum));
```

That gives me the output:

```
Checksum: ce4
```

Of course this means you might have to convert your `byte array` beforehand.

Comment: This will still sign-extend. You have to mask.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got...

corrected code

```
void CalculateCheckSum( byte[] bytes ){
         short CheckSum = 0, i = 0;
         for( i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++){
              CheckSum += (short)(bytes[i] & 0xFF);
         }
         Log.i("Checksum", Integer.toHexString(CheckSum));
    }
```

thanks to aprian and others

Comment: Thanks to Aprian? He was completely wrong, and he didn't give you this code. Only two answers gave you this code, and you should accept one of those, not your own. Posting your own when those others exist is a waste of time and space.

Answer (score -1):

You should use integers as input if you convert them with:

```
    String CalculateCheckSum( Integer[] bytes ){
        Integer CheckSum = 0, i = 0;
        for( i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++ ){
            CheckSum += bytes[i];
        }
        return Integer.toHexString(CheckSum);
    }
```

this will return the expected 0xCE4 hope this fixed your problem

Comment: But he doesn't have integers, or Integers, as input.