# Converting mac address to integer resulting in number format exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("4B5CE3D77A73",16);
```

throws me a number format exception. and the mac address is valid one which is generated from this site http://www.miniwebtool.com/mac-address-generator/

Do i miss something here ?

Comment: Ethernet and Wireless LAN have 6 byte (48 bit) MAC addresses while `int` in Java has only 32 bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like the number is greater than what Integer can hold. Try with Long:

```
Long.parseLong("4B5CE3D77A73",16)
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) states that it throws `NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer`. Not only if the string contains invalid characters but also if the number is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Hey thanks paco , now i feel very foolish. By the way how can I know latest  questions java. So that I can help others.

Comment: Clic the tag Java under your question or better: write `[java]` in the Stack Overlow's search box.

Comment: any desktop app regarding this in mac, or some rss feeds, any how thanks for the help

Comment: You should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/281502) as a valid answer any of the correct answers. So the question is marked as resolved and could help other people in the future. Also you provide of some [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) for you and the one that answered.

Comment: hey sorry paco, I am new hear,  I assumed the clicking on the arrow mark is way of acception the answer @Paco. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The number does not fit to an integer, which's maximum value is:

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // prints 2147483647
```

Try the following:

```
Long.parseLong("4B5CE3D77A73",16); // 0x4B5CE3D77A73 == 82862331624051
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) stack overflow is faster than asking someone behind your desk

Answer (score 0):

i think you should convert it to hexa format.
this may help you.

[try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527926/converting-string-mac-address-to-hex)

Comment: I think this doesn't really answer the question. better just leave it as a comment