# I have a C # DNS encryption algorithm now want to change it to the java but java byte is -128~127 , C# is 0~255

Tags: java

```
private static final byte[] BitPMC1 = { 56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8, 0, 57,
        49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9, 1, 58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 10, 2, 59, 51,
        43, 35, 62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14, 6, 61, 53, 45, 37, 29, 21, 13,
        5, 60, 52, 44, 36, 28, 20, 12, 4, 27, 19, 11, 3 };

 byte[] outData= new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

 for (int i = 0; i < 56; i++) {
     if ((inData[BitPMC1[i] >> 3] & (1 << (7 - (BitPMC1[i] & 0x07)))) != 0) {
    outData[i >> 3] |= (1 << (7 - (i & 0x07)));
     }
 }
```

---

```
java  outData[i >> 3]  and c#  different
```

Comment: please show example input and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Your input values are all in the range 0..127 so there's no problem there.

On the output, but *only* after all the calculations are done, you need to convert the `byte` values into `int` values, whilst also converting the twos-complement negative values to positive:

```
int unsigned_value = ((int)byte_value) & 0xff;
```

If you output each element of the array per the above, you *should* find that the values you get out match your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't describe what your code should do (e.g. giving some example numbers) thus I can only guess.

Having unsigned data, it does not make sense to use an operation taking care of the sign bit (`>>`), probably the operation you need is a logical shift (`>>>`)

More details here: [Difference between >>> and >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and)

Comment: none of the right shifts are on "negative" numbers therefore there's no need to use `>>>` instead of `>>`.

Comment: @Alnitak: You are right, for the given input values there is no difference. I assumed the code should be fine for the full byte range.

Comment: Whilst _in general_ it makes sense not to use `>>` when manipulating "unsigned" data, in the OP's case this would not resolve his problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use the operator >>> instead of >>, you can have problems when your number is higher than 127, it would become something negative.
Well, this might help you:
[Can we make unsigned byte in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java)

Cheers

Comment: per my comment on one of the other answers - none of the numbers on which the right shift operator are used are outside the range `0 .. 127` so there's no need to use the unsigned shift operator.

Comment: But it will be after applying the operator >> 3 times. If the number is >=32, after moving three bits it becomes 128, which is already a negative number. If it were unsigned byte, it will work well, but if 7 bits are used instead of 8, the result would be different. But this just depends on what the function should do.

Comment: No, look again.  There are only two right shifts - `BitPMC1[i] >> 3` and `i >> 3`.  The `BitPMC1` array is constant and only contains values `0..127`.  `i` is the loop counter and goes from `0 .. 55`.

Comment: Which is higher than 32

Comment: huh?  It's only "signed" values with bit 7 set (i.e. negative numbers, or "unsigned" values > 127) that would be affected.  32 doesn't come into it.