# How to convert an int to byte while keeping order

Tags: java, int, byte, signed

I am working with Local Binary Patterns (LBP) which produce numbers in the range 0-255. 
That means that they can fit in a byte (256 different values may be included into a byte). So that explains why many (if not all) implementation in java I have found uses `byte[]` to store these values.

The problem is that since I am interested in the rank of these values when converted to `byte` (from `int` for example) they do not keep the previous rank they had (as `int` for example) since byte are signed (as all but chars in java I think) and so the greater 128 values (127 and after) of the range 0-255 becomes negative numbers. Furthermore I think they are inverted in order (the negative ones).

Some examples to be more specific:

```
(int) 0 = (byte) 0
(int) 20 = (byte) 20
(int) 40 = (byte) 40
(int) 60 = (byte) 60
(int) 80 = (byte) 80
(int) 100 = (byte) 100
(int) 120 = (byte) 120
(int) 140 = (byte) -116
(int) 160 = (byte) -96
(int) 180 = (byte) -76
(int) 200 = (byte) -56
(int) 220 = (byte) -36
(int) 240 = (byte) -16
```

My question is whether there is a specific way to maintain the order of `int` values when converted to `byte` (meaning `240 > 60` should hold true in `byte` also `-16 < 60`!) while keeping memory needs minimum (meaning use only 8bits if that many are required). I know I could consider comparing the byte in a more complex way (for example every negative > positive and if both `byte`s are negative inverse the order) but I think it's not that satisfactory.

Is there any other way to convert to `byte` besides `(byte) i`?

Comment: Perhaps this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/4266841/564045

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could subtract 128 from the value:

```
byte x = (byte) (value - 128);
```

That would be order-preserving, and reversible later by simply adding 128 again. Be careful to make sure you *do* add 128 later on though... It's as simple as:

```
int value = x + 128;
```

So for example, if you wanted to convert between an `int[]` and `byte[]` in a reversible way:

```
public byte[] toByteArray(int[] values) {
    byte[] ret = new byte[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = (byte) (values[i] - 128);
    }
    return ret;
}

public int[] toIntArray(int[] values) {
    int[] ret = new byte[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = values[i] + 128;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If you wanted to keep the original values though, the byte comparison wouldn't need to be particularly complex:

```
int unsigned1 = byte1 & 0xff;
int unsigned2 = byte2 & 0xff;
// Now just compare unsigned1 and unsigned2...
```

Comment: The order-keeping function is really cool but the keeping the original value does not work correctly on the positive number. I don't know if I misinterpreted something. Anyway thanks

Comment: @Eypros: It certainly should do. I've edited the answer as an example.