# How to display a hex/byte value in Java

Tags: java, int, hex, byte

```
int myInt = 144;
byte myByte = /* Byte conversion of myInt */;
```

Output should be `myByte : 90` (hex value of 144).

So, I did:

```
byte myByte = (byte)myInt;
```

I got output of `myByte : ffffff90`. :(

How can I get rid of those `ffffff`s?

Comment: Why it should be 90? You're not doing hex conversion there. Value 144 is out of `byte` range and will overflow, and hence that value (a negative amount).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is now marked as a duplicate of the wrong question, because the question isn't about how to convert an `int` to a `byte` (despite the incorrect title), but about how to get rid of extra 1 bits when converting the `byte` back to an `int`.  Voting to reopen--perhaps it can be closed as a duplicate of a more appropriate question.

Comment: I am sorry if I am messing this up :), I am a C++ developer and newbie to java, in C++ i know how to do this, int -> unsigned int -> unsigned char, but in JAVA I'm really confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`byte` is a signed type.  Its values are in the range -128 to 127; 144 is not in this range.  There is no unsigned byte type in Java.

If you are using Java 8, the way to treat this as a value in the range 0 to 255 is to use `Byte.toUnsignedInt`:

```
String output = String.format("%x", Byte.toUnsignedInt(myByte));
```

(I don't know how you formatted the integer for hex output.  It doesn't matter.)

Pre-Java 8, the easiest way is

```
int byteValue = (int)myByte & 0xFF;
String output = String.format("%x", byteValue);
```

But before you do either of those, make sure you really want to use a `byte`.  Chances are you don't need to.  And if you want to represent the value 144, you shouldn't use a `byte`, if you don't need to.  Just use an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @ajb and @sumit, I used both the answers,

```
int myInt = 144;

byte myByte = (byte) myInt;

char myChar = (char) (myByte & 0xFF);

System.out.println("myChar :"+Integer.toHexString(myChar));
```

o/p,

```
myChar : 90
```