# Java, store in byte higher value than 127

Tags: java, casting, byte

For an assignment I get some bytes, make some calculations on their Binary values and have to return that calculated Stuff in a Byte Array.

My Problem is now, that byte only stores up to 127, but my values can be up to 2^8-1 (11111111). I already tried to convert it to hex, but it´s of course not working either.

So, is that possible, if yes how, or is that exercise not possible like that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java

Comment: Would you mind posting some of your code? It will really help :)

Comment: what is the problem if your results requires 2 bytes? don't you need to just return a Byte Array?

Comment: I don´t understand what you mean nafas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, before you perform any calculations you need to AND (&) your bytes against 255, so you'll be dealing with values from 0 to 255 instead of -128 to 127.  When you assign a value higher than 127 to a byte it overflows, so 128 as a byte in java is -128, but after you AND (&) -128 against 255 you'll get +128.

```
// This prints 0 to 127, then -128 to -1
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
        System.out.println(((byte)i));
    }
}

// Where this will print 0 to 255
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
        System.out.println(((byte)i) & 255);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really get around the problem, though. In your first version, you're calling `System.out.println(byte)`, and in the second one, `System.out.println(int)`. Importantly, the `&` operation is promoting `i` to `int` because the literal 255 is an `int`.

Comment: @gobernador It's an explanation of how bytes are stored from the minimum value to the maximum value.  To me it sounds like the OP wants to work with values from 0 - 255, which with a byte can still be done.  I'm merely demonstrating how that's done.

Comment: Thanks, that´s it. But I don´t get why it´s from 0 to 255 if it AND it with 255. I suppose that a normal byte is up to 01111111, and when I add an 1 it looks like 10000000, which is then -128 ? If I have now 01111111 +1 = 10000000 & FF , wouldn´t it be 11111111?

Comment: @EsoMoa In Java, the Most Significant Bit (MSB) is the sign bit.  It determines if a number of positive or negative.  When you AND (&) against 255 (An integer [4 bytes]), as gobemador said, the byte gets promoted to an integer (32 bits where the sign bit is now the 32 bit vs the 8 bit for a byte).  So if you have 0111111 + 1 = 10000000 & FF you would get 00000000000000000000000010000000 which is positive 128.

Comment: @EsoMoa If you found that my answer helped you solve your issue, kindly click the check mark to my answer so you question is solved.

Comment: Yes. of course. But I had to think about your answer. So that means since I use 0xff is bigger than byte it "casts" the intern "Register" ? to an int.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, in Java, this number would be represented as an `int`. That gives you more than enough room to store your values. If you need to represent it as a byte, for transmitting it somewhere or something like that, then you would cast it like

```
int i = 255;
byte b = (byte) (i & 0xff);
```

but in this case, it will still be negative, because `byte` is signed in Java.

Also, hexadecimal literals are by default of type `int`, as you've probably found out. So `0xff` does have the value of 255 like you intend, but it's an `int`, not a `byte`.

Comment: hmm alternatively **char** could be used as its maximum value is 255.

Comment: `char` is 16 bits wide, so its maximum value is 65535, but you're correct that it is unsigned. In my experience, though, `char` is very rarely used.

Comment: `(byte)i` is just fine :) The problem arises when doing `byte->int`