# [Java]How to correct the overflowing variables generated from the situation we capture the single byte of data from files?

Tags: java, hex, byte, decimal, overflow

As tilte,

I tried to capture the file size info which is saved in 4 bytes of data from bitmap's file code,

but if I use byte[] to save it and any byte of file exceeds 127, it'd be misjudged as negative values,

in this case how could we correct these kind of values?

My book just simply plus 256 to it, but could it fixedly be -128?

if not, then the result still isn't correct.

I know we can just use int[] or larger array for it, just wanna know how to deal with these kind of problems!

Thanks a lot for helping!!!

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Sry mate it's JAVA!!Thx!!!!

Comment: sry for the rookie problem guys, but I really don't know why is the question going that way@@, plz enlighten me & it'll be truly appreciated!!

Comment: A question that is clear and easy to read will usually get more replies. Here's some tips on how to write a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Håken Lid thx so much man!!I've updated my title, BTW do u know the situation of my question?

Comment: Check this question about signed vs unsigned bytes in Java. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java

Comment: Thx @HåkenLid, but actually the answers supported the most are not exactly the right answer lol...but I still figured it out myself, thx a lot man!