# Declare byte[] in java?

Tags: java, android

i try :

`byte[] Data = { 0xA3, 0x34, 0x33, 0x33, 0x00};`

but at "0xA3" it said "required byte found int",so what's problem here ?

Comment: `byte`s range from -128 to 127. `0xA3` is 163.

Comment: @paulsm4 -128 to 127.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0xA3` is 163 which is out of bounds for `byte` which I think can be -128 ->  +127.

You can find more details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: i do that in C#, so in JAVA what i need to do ?

Comment: I think you are looking for an unsigned byte? You might find something [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4266756/2650847).

Comment: @HảiDuyNguyễn Cast it to byte: `byte[] Data = { (byte)0xA3, 0x34, 0x33, 0x33, 0x00};`

Answer (score 1):

> at "0xA3" it said "required byte found int", so what's problem here

The problem is that the range of a byte in Java is -128..127.

The solution is that you need to write a `(byte)` cast in front of 0xA3.