# difference between FileHandle in Swift 3.0 and FileInputStream in java

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

in java I use this code too read mp3 file in to buffer

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[12];
stream.read(buffer, offset, 12 - offset); 
for(int i = 0; i<buffer.length ; i++){
     Log.e("buff","buff "+ buffer[i]);
}
```

and here's result of  buffer

```
69 82 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 -50 -76 -42
```

in swift 3.0

```
var buffer = Data()
let file = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: urlLocal)
file.seek(toFileOffset: 0)
buffer = file.readData(ofLength: 12)
for  i in  0...(buffer.count-1){
            print(buffer[i])
}
```

and here is result of buffer

```
69 82 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 206 180 214
```

I think Data in swift use Unit8 data type that reason I have difference output. My question, in swift how can I get output same java. thank you so much !

**EDIT :**  output code

Comment: Update both sets of code showing how you print the buffers.

Comment: looks like java prints out its values signed, while swift is unsigned, aka -50 = 206 etc ... -128 - 128 vs 0 - 256

Comment: FYI - since you are dealing with byte data, I'd suggest you update the Java code to print like the Swift code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your java code you can try do [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4266841/1219956) which is quite straight forward to make it unsigned while printing

```
for(int i = 0; i<buffer.length ; i++){
     Log.e("buff","buff "+ (buffer[i] & 0xFF));
}
```

Comment: Thank Fonix for your answer! how can I convert 206 to -56

Comment: sorry I have mistake, I wanna convert 206 to -50 , 180 to -76, 214 to -42 as above question

Answer (score 1):

`Data` is a collection of unsigned bytes (`UInt8`). If you really
want to print them as signed bytes  then you can use
`Int8(bitPattern:)` which creates a signed value with the same
memory representation:

```
let buffer = Data(bytes: [69, 82, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 206, 180, 214])
for byte in buffer {
    print(Int8(bitPattern: byte))
}
// 69 82 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 -50 -76 -42
```

Or create an `[Int8]` array from the data and print the array:

```
let signedByteArray = buffer.map { Int8(bitPattern: $0) } // [Int8]
print(signedByteArray)
// [69, 82, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, -50, -76, -42]
```

Comment: this is what I need, thank you so much !. I really wanna give this answer one thumbs up but I dont have enough reputation now . sorry !!