# How to create unsigned byte array in java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, byte

I want to create one byte array which should be able to handled the unsigned values. I have gone through this link on stack overflow. [Can we make unsigned byte in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java).. It is mentioned in the answer that **Java does not allow to express 244 as a byte value, as would C** I want to have my byte array like this that 
byte [0] should have a value 239 and byte[1] should have a values as 245.

As per the documentation it is mentioned that we can only save value in a range-128 to 128 in byte.. how should i solve this problem?

Comment: Have you used Guava's `UnsignedByte` http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.html ?

Comment: No.. I havent tried this.Will check now. Thanks for immediate response.

Comment: Did you understand what the linked question was about? Signed / unsigned is about human representation. Writing something like `byte b = (byte)239;` will result in the same **bits** in `b` as `unsigned byte b = 239;`.