# Byte conversion from hash string, java vs python

Tags: java, python, hash, byte

I have issue with converting a pure java Curve25519 function to Python equivalent, the specific problem is related to digest function that convert hash string to byte equivalent, the java implementation :

Data example :

sP = "this is a sample of secret pass phrase for test purpose"

```
/**
 * Calculate the SHA-256 hash of a string
 *
 * @param       input           Data to be hashed
 * @return                      The hash digest
 */
public static byte[] singleDigest(String input) {
    byte[] bytes;
    try {
        bytes = singleDigest(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("bytes"+bytes);
        System.out.println("before singleDigest"+input);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exc) {
        bytes = null;
    }
    return bytes;
}

/**
 * Calculate the SHA-256 hash of a byte array
 *
 * @param       input           Data to be hashed
 * @return                      The hash digest
 */
public static byte[] singleDigest(byte[] input) {
    byte[] bytes;
    synchronized (digest) {
        digest.reset();
        bytes = digest.digest(input);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(bytes[i]);
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", bytes[i] & 0xFF));
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Generate this byte output :

byteOutput :82, -57, 124, 58, -105, 76, 123, 3, 119, -21, 121, 71, -54, 73, -75, 54, 31, -33, -49, -68, -16, -19, 125, -61, -116, -82, 96, 50, -35, -119, -28, 25

with positive and negative numbers, on python side, I use this function to convert a hashed string to byte :

```
secret = sha256(sP.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
sct = ParseHexString(secret).getData()

class ParseHexString(object):

    def __init__(self, hex):
        """

        """
        if not isinstance(hex, str):
            return None
        else:

            self.hex = hex
            self.listOfByte = None

        self.run()

    def run(self):

        if len(self.hex)&0x01 == 1:
            return None

        lbytes = []
        for i in range(0, len(self.hex), 2):
            op1, op2 = self.hex[i:i + 2]
            oop1 = ord(op1)
            oop2 = ord(op2)

            char1 = oop1 - 0x57 if oop1 > 0x60 else oop1 - 0x30
            char2 = oop2 - 0x57 if oop2 > 0x60 else oop2 - 0x30

            if (char1 < 0 or char2 < 0 or char1 > 15 or char2 > 15):
                print("Invalid hex number ",op1,op2)

            lbytes.append(((char1 << 4) + char2))

        self.listOfByte = lbytes

    def getData(self):
        return self.listOfByte
```

I used lists here instead of mutable bytearray because of internal representation of bytearray (0 - 256), and the output for some hashed string 
is different and is only positive integers :

82, 199, 124, 58, 151, 76, 123, 3, 119, 235, 121, 71, 202, 73, 181, 54, 31, 217, 207, 188, 240, 237, 125, 196, 140, 174, 96, 50, 221, 137, 228, 25

I noticed that (256 - JavaByteOutput[x] == PythonByteOtput[x]) when JavaByteOutput is a negative number, the question is, how I can modify my ParseHexString class to have equivalent positive/negative output, and I want pure python code and no libraries.

Thanks for any kind answer.
Regards
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, `a % b` always returns a value with the same sign as `b` between 0 (inclusive) and `b` (exclusive). In this case `b` is 256.

So to shift the values to the range [-128, 128), add 128 to each value, take the modulus base 256 then subtract 128:

```
x = [82, 199, 124, 58, 151, 76, 123, 3, 119, 235, 121, 71, 202, 73, 181, 54, 31, 217, 207, 188, 240, 237, 125, 196, 140, 174, 96, 50, 221, 137, 228, 25]

y = [(xi + 128) % 256 - 128 for xi in x]
# [82, -57, 124, 58, -105, 76, 123, 3, 119, -21, 121, 71, -54, 73, -75, 54, 31, -39, -49, -68, -16, -19, 125, -60, -116, -82, 96, 50, -35, -119, -28, 25]
```

Therefore, in `ParseHexString.run` define:

```
self.listOfByte = [(xi + 128) % 256 - 128 for xi in lbytes]
```

---

If NumPy were an option, you could instead simply [`view`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) the unsigned 1-byte ints as signed 1-byte ints:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([82, 199, 124, 58, 151, 76, 123, 3, 119, 235, 121, 71, 202, 73, 181, 54, 31, 217, 207, 188, 240, 237, 125, 196, 140, 174, 96, 50, 221, 137, 228, 25], dtype='uint8')

x.view('i1')
# array([  82,  -57,  124,   58, -105,   76,  123,    3,  119,  -21,  121,
#          71,  -54,   73,  -75,   54,   31,  -39,  -49,  -68,  -16,  -19,
#         125,  -60, -116,  -82,   96,   50,  -35, -119,  -28,   25], dtype=int8)
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole point here: Java only knows **signed** types.

This means: although the Java byte is also about 8 bits, the range is from -128 to 127. Unsigned bytes go from 0 to 255.

That is all there is to this. The only thing that really matters is that you are consistent about how the values dealt with. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java) for some further thoughts on this topic.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and suggestions!