# Reading in WAV data using Java - Endianness is not working for some values?

Tags: java, audio, hex, wav

I am using Java to read in WAV data. With the WAV data being little-endian and Java using big-endian, I was looking to convert the values upon reading them in, as shown below, which I will then manipulate.

However, it seems to be working only partially for certain values.
The first image shows the original WAV data, which should be read in as `98 00` and then swapped, to get `00 98`, which would equate to `152` in decimal. My code below is however receiving the value `-104` in decimal, which eqautes to simply `98` in hex. Note that this code should be able to take in negative values, as this is important to the use of the WAV data once it is read in.

This can equally seen a bit further down the same line as the higlighted values when the first value in the byte is above 80.

[image: Original wav sample]
[image: Read in and saved wav sample]

```
public boolean read (String filename) {

    try {
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));

        if (!(riff_header.read(input))) {
            return false;
        }

        nSamples = (riff_header.getData_size() / riff_header.getBytes_samp());
        System.out.println("Number of samples: " + nSamples);

        sample = new int[nSamples];
        System.out.println("Sizeof sample: " + sample.length);

        // Should sample two bytes at a time (if 1 channel WAV)
        byte[] bytes = new byte[riff_header.getBytes_samp()];
        // incrementing by bytes_samp every iteration ( in this case, for test_file.wav = 2 bytes)
        for (int i = 0; i < riff_header.getData_size(); i+=riff_header.getBytes_samp()) {


            if (i / riff_header.getBytes_samp() == 402) {
                System.out.println("break");
            }

            input.read(bytes);
            // note - working backwards through array - endian order
            int joined = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
                joined = joined | (int) (((bytes[(bytes.length - 1) - j]) << ((bytes.length - 1) - j) * 8));
            }

            sample[i / riff_header.getBytes_samp()] = joined;

        } 
        input.close();

        return true;
```

Howw

Comment: `byte` is a signed value - you need to treat it as unsigned here - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4266756/2670892)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html) will help so you don't have to deal with the raw values?

Comment: @greg-449 Super, that fixed it. Thanks very much!

Comment: @greg-449 Unfortunately as it turns out, for my WAV analysis I require negative numbers. I have correctly read some in earlier but I don't know why this particular one isn't working. ;(