# Java convert unsigned big integer to unsigned byte

Tags: java, bit, biginteger, unsigned

How to convert unsigned BigInteger into unsigned byte when the value is higher?

```
String value = "202";
BigInteger a = new BigInteger( value );
Byte b = new BigInteger( value ).byteValue() // returns -54
```

How to get unsigned byte value from BigInteger?

Comment: There's no such thing as an "unsigned byte" type in Java. The `byte` type is *always* signed. This is entirely separate to `BigInteger` - you'd see the same behaviour if you cast an `int` value of 202 to `byte`.

Comment: As it is unlikely that you are really going to store `byte`-sized numbers in `BigInteger`-s, you might consider describing what you are planning to do with that number afterwards.

Comment: @tevemadar after that I need to compare this number with database stored value.

Comment: @JonSkeet in general how can I store and retrieve values which are > 128

Comment: Why `byte` and `BigInteger` then? Are you aware of functions like `Integer.parseInt(<some string>)`? You could very well write `int i = Integer.parseInt(value);`, and compare that to the number you have in DB. And if your numbers grow large, remember that `BigInteger` has a [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo(java.math.BigInteger)) method.

Answer (score 1):

you should cast "202" to `int` because java does not have `unsigned byte`.
I suppose `.intValue()` would help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you looking for something like this:

```
import java.math.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String value = "202";
        BigInteger a = new BigInteger( value );
        Byte b = new BigInteger( value ).byteValue() ;
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(unsignedToBytes((byte)b));
    }

    public static int unsignedToBytes(byte b) {
    return (int)b & 0xFF;
  }
}
```

and here is a very good explanation:
[Can we make unsigned byte in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java)