# How to get integer array from byte array in java and print the output array? Byte array is from a grayscale image of 225*225 dimension

Tags: java, arrays

Here I am type casting the byte array `data[]` to `int`. But getting positive and negetive integer values as output array in `arr[i]`. But pixel values should come positive right? For grayscale (0 to 255) I think I am  converting wrong way. Can anyone please suggest some code to convert my byte array `data[]` to integer 1D array `arr[]`?

```
public class Imagemat {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  { 
        //*************convert byte array*************//
        BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File("image path"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray(); //byte array data[]

         //*****convert to integer array *****//
        int[] arr = new int[data.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int)data[i];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + "  "); //integer array arr[i]
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Getting output like:

```
-1  -40  -1  -32  0  16  74  70  73  70  0  1  2  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  -1  -37  0  67  0  8  6  6  7  
6  5  8  7  7  7  9  9  8  10  12  20  13  12  11  11  1........
```

Comment: See there [Can we make unsigned byte in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java)

Comment: jpeg files contains compressed data, you need to research how to read a jpeg file

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how JPG images are stored in bytes, but to convert a unsigned byte to an `int` you can use `Byte.toUnsignedInt(byte x)` to get the unsigned value of a byte. (This function just returns `((int) x) & 0xff` so you can use that instead if you want)

Example:

```
int[] arr = new int[data.length];
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   arr[i] = Byte.toUnsignedInt(data[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   System.out.print(arr[i] + "  "); //integer array arr[i]
   System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: actually I am trying to convert a grayscale image to integer 2D array or matrix.
using following code i am getting byte array data [] 

      BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File("grayscale.jpg"));
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", bos );
      byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();

after this I am trying to convert it to int 2D array. First getting 1D array , then converting to 2D array..

Comment: I am not sure whether the data is coming correctly after converting byte to unsigned Int. total length of byte array is showing 3962. But how to divide this size as row and column? Can you please help me? the image dimension is 225*225.

Comment: @S.Podder Again you need to realise the data is compressed and stored in a specific format so you can just read the file and expect it to correspond 1:1 to your 255x255 sized image. A simple math example, if your file is using 8 bit then the size should be 255*255 byte which is about 63.5 Kb. Your array is less than 4 Kb.