# How to include a positive 8-bit number in byte array in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to simulate a virtual IP datagram to send through DatagramPacket, which accepts byte array only.
However, many headers in IP datagram are 16-bit long. What I'm trying to do is to divide it into 2 8-bit number, but the byte in Java is -127 to 127, what I want is 0 - 256. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Store it as a byte; convert to/from an unsigned short when you need the value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Java handles arrays of bytes perfectly fine. Show example of your code where the signed value of a byte is causing trouble.

Comment: *Hint:* For working with byte array data structures, you should use `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: So is it okay to include a negative number in a byte array and put it in a DatagramPacket?